# Integrate $\int\sec ^2 x \tan x\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to compute
$$
\int\sec^2 x \tan x\, dx.
$$
I substituted $u =\sec^2 x$ to get the integral as 
$$
\frac{\sec^4x}{2}
$$
as my answer, but according to the textbook I am using, I'm wrong. Can anyone help me with the correct answer? According to my textbook, the correct option is between  (a) $2\sec^2 x$ (b) $\tan x$ (c) $1/2 \sec x$ or (d)  $\csc x \cot x$

Comment: What is the derivative of $\tan x$?

Comment: Exactly, why don't you put $u = \tan x$ instead ?

Comment: "according to the textbook I'm wrong": you didn't try checking your answer yourself by differentiating your answer to see if you got back the original function? You should.

Answer (score 4):

When you do a substitution like that in an integral, you want to 
end up with something that looks like this:

$$\int u \; du.$$

If $u = \sec^2 x$, what is $du$? If it is not $\tan x\;dx$ then
you will not be able to change $\sec^2 x \tan x \; dx$ to 
$u \; du$.

Try a different substitution. There are not many choices,
in fact I see only three likely possibilities and $u = \sec^2 x$ is the
only one of the three that does *not* work.

**EDIT:** John Joy, in another answer, shows that the substitution
$u = \sec^2 x$ actually *does* work if you do it correctly.
You do not get anything in the form of $\int u\;du$ that way;
instead, you get something easier.
I should have acknowledged earlier that while $\int u\;du$ is *one* form
you might hope to achieve from a substitution, really the point is just
to get the integral into *some* form you know how to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Notice, we have $$\int\sec^2x \tan x dx$$ Let $\tan x=t\implies \sec^2 xdx=dt$
$$=\int tdt$$ $$=\frac{t^2}{2}+C$$ setting the value $t=\tan x$  $$=\frac{(\tan x)^2}{2}+C$$$$=\color{red}{\frac{\tan^2x}{2}+C}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your substitution $u=\sec^2 x$ is actually a good one, but it looks like you made an error somewhere.

$$\int\sec^2x\tan x dx$$
$$u = \sec^2 x\implies du = 2\sec x\cdot\sec x\tan xdx = 2\sec^2x\tan x dx$$
so the integral becomes
$$\int\sec^2x\tan x dx = \int\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\sec^2 x\tan xdx=\int \frac{1}{2}du=\frac{1}{2}u+C=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2x+C$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. My answer was too quick to suggest that $\int u\;du$ is "the" form that one wants the integral to take after substitution.

Comment: It works, but its kind of like cheating because it presupposes that you already know the answer. The best substitution here: $u=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2x$ hehe

Comment: Yes, one way to do this is if you already know the answer. Or you can just _guess_ that the substitution might work, calculate $du$, and see what you can make of it. And oh, look, lucky guess. It seems to me that a lot of integration is like that--you recognize an integral you've seen before, or you try a particular trick to see if it works. At least that was my experience with first-year calculus, and thankfully after that I didn't have to remember most of that stuff except when I was _teaching_ it.

Comment: The guess $u = \frac12 \sec^2 x$ actually makes a lot of sense even before you know the answer, because you can already see there's probably going to be a factor of $2$ in the derivative of $\sec^2 x$, so by multiplying by $\frac12$ you trade off a more complicated $u$ for a simpler $du$ (which is often a good tradeoff).

Answer (score 1):

The last two answers, from Harish and egreg, are the same.  Integrating egreg's construction produces $\frac{\sec^2x}{2} + C$, and that from Harish produces $\frac{tan^2x}{2} + C_1$. Choosing $C_1 = 1/2 + C$ for the latter, yields $\frac{tan^2x+1}{2} + C = \frac{sec^2x}{2} + C,$ as it should.

Answer (score 1):

∫Sec^2x.Tanx dx
But we know d(Secx)/dx = Secx.Tanx

By substituting we change the integral to the form,

∫Secx d(Secx)

This is of the form

∫xdx

..

So we have ,

Sec^2x/2 +C

Where C is an arbitrary constant. Feel free to edit

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remember complicated formulas: just recall
$$
\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x},\qquad
\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}
$$
so your integral is
$$
\int \frac{\sin x}{\cos^3 x}\,dx=
\int -\frac{1}{t^3}\,dt
$$
with the substitution $t=\cos x$.

Comment: I think it is helpful to remember some of the somewhat more complicated trig integrals and derivatives when you need to come up with a more "creative" method to solve a harder problem, like $\int \sec(x)^m \tan(x)^n dx$ for various positive integers $m,n$. I don't know how I would come up with the procedure for these kinds of problems without thinking things like "substituting $u=\sec(x)$ will absorb a secant and a tangent into the du", "substituting $u=\tan(x)$ will absorb two secants into the du" and "secants and tangents can be interconverted two at a time using $\sec(x)^2=\tan(x)^2+1$".

Comment: @Ian I'm not saying that those formulas are useless (but I believe they're sometimes abused); first go with simple methods, I think this is better.

Comment: I actually prefer Using $\tan$ and $\sec$ because they seem much simpler to me than converting to rational functions. $(\tan x)' = \sec^2 x$ and $(\sec x)' = \sec x \tan x$  go hand-in-hand